# How can I select the specific a-tag and extract its href?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am doing a project which requires webscraping news content (the whole article) from websites.
the page I am scraping is https://tg24.sky.it/politica, and I got the headlines with the following code:

```
r= requests.get('https://tg24.sky.it/politica')
b= soup(r.content, 'lxml')

title=[]

for c in b.findAll('h2',{'class':'c-card__title'}):
   title.append(c.text.strip())
```

Now I want to scrape the href and through it acces the whole content . I am having trouble extracting the `href`
In the webiste the `href` is in

```
<a class="c-card c-card--CA05C-m c-card--CA15-t c-card--CA15-d c-card--media  c-card--base" href="https://tg24.sky.it/politica/2022/07/15/crisi-governo-draghi-ultime-notizie">
        <article class="c-card__wrapper aem_card_check_wrapper">
            <div class="c-card__content">
                
                <h2 class="c-card__title">Governo Draghi, le ultime notizie sulla crisi aperta da Conte e M5S</h2>
```

How can I extract the `href`
I tried

```
for c in b.findAll('a',{'class':'c-card c-card--CA10-m c-card--CA15-t c-card--CA15-d c-card--media  c-card--base '}):
    links.append(c.a['href'])
```

but it does not work.

Comment: Could it be possible that those content are dynamic, if yes use selenium

Answer (score 2):

I would change the following:

1. Get the `href` directly: replace `c.a['href']` with `c.get("href")`
2. Specify multiple classes inside a `list`: `soup.findAll("a", {"class": ["c-card", "c-card--CA10-m"]})`

In code:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://tg24.sky.it/politica"

response = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "lxml")

links = []
for link in soup.find_all("a", {"class": ["c-card", "c-card--CA10-m"]}):
    links.append(link.get("href"))

print(links)
```

NOTE: I haven't added all the classes, just enough to prove my point.

### EDIT 1

As @HedgeHog suggests in the comments, it is preferred to use the newer `find_all()` version of the method, instead of `findAll()`.

You can the complete list of method names on the [official docs](https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html?highlight=findall#method-names).

I have updated the code above with these changes.

### EDIT 2

As @HedgeHog suggests in the comments, and I previously considered but not wrote, it would be better to use the `get()` method on the `Tag` object in case the `href` attribute is not present, in which case it would return `None` and not raise a `KeyError`.

I have updated the code above with these changes.

Comment: In newer code avoid old syntax `findAll()` instead use `find_all()` - For more take a minute to [check docs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#method-names), also try to access the values of an attribute not directly, to avoid errors if it is empty or not available use `.get()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you wanna work with different `lists` but you should avoid this, in case some information is not available they become different length. So try to scrape all information in one go and store it in more structured way.

To get the links you could select them directly:

```
soup.find_all('a', {'class': 'c-card'})
```

or if you come frome your title use [`.find_previous('a').get('href')`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all-previous-and-find-previous) on your element:

```
data = []
for e in soup.find_all('h2', {'class': 'c-card__title'}):
    data.append({
        'title': e.get_text(strip=True),
        'url':e.find_previous('a').get('href')
    })
```

`data` would look like:

```
[{'title': 'Letta: "Draghi continui". Salvini: minacce le lascio a signori del No', 'url': 'https://tg24.sky.it/politica/2022/07/16/crisi-governo-draghi'}, {'title': 'Governo Draghi: chi sono i ministri, vice e sottosegretari del M5S', 'url': 'https://tg24.sky.it/politica/2022/07/16/ministri-movimento-5-stelle-governo-draghi'}, {'title': 'Crisi di governo, cosa ha portato Draghi a volersi dimettere', 'url': 'https://tg24.sky.it/politica/2022/07/16/crisi-governo-draghi-perche'}, {'title': 'Crisi governo: se si andasse al voto ora come finirebbe? LE GRAFICHE', 'url': 'https://tg24.sky.it/politica/2022/07/16/crisi-governo-simulazioni-risultati-elezioni'}, {'title': 'Governo Draghi, le ultime notizie sulla crisi aperta da Conte e M5S', 'url': 'https://tg24.sky.it/politica/2022/07/15/crisi-governo-draghi-ultime-notizie'}, {'title': 'Governo in bilico, Draghi deciso a lasciare e partiti nel caos', 'url': 'https://tg24.sky.it/politica/2022/07/15/crisi-governo-draghi'}, {'title': 'Patuanelli: "Ritiro ministri M5S? Dimissionario è il governo"', 'url': 'https://tg24.sky.it/politica/2022/07/15/crisi-governo-ritiro-ministri-m5s-patuanelli'},...]
```

**Note:** *In newer code avoid old syntax `findAll()` instead use `find_all()` - For more take a minute to [check docs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#method-names)*

##### Example

Scrape all information and display as DataFrame:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

response = requests.get('https://tg24.sky.it/politica')
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text)

data = []

for a in soup.find_all('a', {'class': 'c-card'}):

    response = requests.get(a.get('href'))
    asoup = BeautifulSoup(response.text)
    data.append({
        'url': a.get('href'),
        'title': a.h2.get_text(strip=True),
        'content': asoup.article.get_text(strip=True)
    })

pd.DataFrame(data)
```

###### Output

*Texts of content somewhat shortened for clarity*

|  | url | title | content |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | https://tg24.sky.it/politica/2022/07/16/crisi-governo-draghi | Letta: "Draghi continui". Salvini: minacce le lascio a signori del No | Crisi Governo, Letta: "Draghi continui". Salvini: "Minacce le lascio ai signori del No"Politica16 lug 2022 - 13:43©AnsaIl segretario dem: "Italia non vuole il voto il 25 settembre". Renzi attacca: "Non ci rassegnamo alla catastrofe voluta da Giuseppe Conte". La Lega critica Letta: "Divide maggioranza, poi chiede unità". Intanto 11 sindaci chiedono al premier di andare avantiascolta articoloCondivi |
| 1 | https://tg24.sky.it/politica/2022/07/16/ministri-movimento-5-stelle-governo-draghi | Governo Draghi: chi sono i ministri, vice e sottosegretari del M5S | Governo Draghi: chi sono i 9 ministri, vice e sottosegretari del Movimento 5 Stelle. FOTOPoliticafotogallery16 lug 2022 - 07:0010 foto©AnsaIn attesa di mercoledì 20 luglio, quando il presidente del Consiglio riferirà in Aula sulla crisi politica delle ultime ore, sono in molti dentro il M5S a chiedere l’uscita dei membri pentastellati dell’esecutivo. Dal capo delegazione Stefano Patuanelli a Carlo |
| 2 | https://tg24.sky.it/politica/2022/07/16/crisi-governo-simulazioni-risultati-elezioni | Crisi governo: se si andasse al voto ora come finirebbe? LE GRAFICHE | Crisi governo: se si andasse al voto ora come finirebbe? LE GRAFICHEPoliticafotogallery16 lug 2022 - 06:3013 fotoYouTrend e Cattaneo Zanetto & CoCosa accadrebbe se si andasse al voto oggi con il Rosatellum? YouTrend e Cattaneo Zanetto & Co hanno condotto una simulazione elettorale con tre scenari: nel primo Pd e M5S sono alleati, nel secondo corrono separati, nel terzo c’è un campo largo composto |
| 3 | https://tg24.sky.it/politica/2022/07/16/crisi-governo-draghi-perche | Crisi di governo, cosa ha portato Draghi a volersi dimettere | Crisi di governo, cosa succede: perché Draghi vuole dimettersiPoliticafotogallery16 lug 2022 - 06:3013 foto©AnsaSecondo il premier "la maggioranza di unità nazionale che ha sostenuto questo governo dalla sua creazione non c'è più". Mentre si attende il suo intervento alle Camere di mercoledì prossimo, circolano voci secondo cui le dimissioni - respinte da Mattarella - sarebbero irrevocabili. Come |

...

Answer (score 0):

If you insist of getting the urls based off `h2` elements, then you can do:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1312.60 Safari/537.17'}

r = requests.get('https://tg24.sky.it/politica', headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
headlines = soup.select('h2')
for headline in  headlines:
    print(headline.parent.parent.parent.get('href'))
```

This will result in

```
https://tg24.sky.it/politica/2022/07/16/crisi-governo-draghi-ultime-notizie
https://tg24.sky.it/politica/2022/07/16/crisi-governo-draghi
https://tg24.sky.it/politica/2022/07/16/ministri-movimento-5-stelle-governo-draghi
https://tg24.sky.it/politica/2022/07/16/crisi-governo-simulazioni-risultati-elezioni
https://tg24.sky.it/politica/2022/07/16/crisi-governo-draghi-perche
https://tg24.sky.it/politica/2022/07/15/crisi-governo-draghi-ultime-notizie
https://tg24.sky.it/politica/2022/07/15/crisi-governo-draghi
https://tg24.sky.it/politica/2022/07/15/crisi-governo-ritiro-ministri-m5s-patuanelli
https://tg24.sky.it/politica/2022/07/15/crisi-governo-italia-mosca
[.....]
```

Comment: A solution that works in the current context. But doesn't this construct look a little fragile? I think `.parent` should not necessarily be used beyond one level, there are other approaches for that.

Comment: You're absolutely right @HedgeHog, but just in case OP insists on grabbing the `h2`s, this will get the job done, and with less complexity. Robustness can be achieved with try/except blocks, if of concern.

Comment: Don't get me wrong, approach starting from `h2` is perfectly fine, I did so too, but isn't `c.find_previous('a').get('href')`, as provided, less complex and safer to guide in this context? It is not my downvote, I am more into discussion.